# Regex exception while removing escape

Tags: java, regex, exception

I'm writing a function to remove the escape characters and it's throwing me `PatternSyntaxException`. What am I missing here? I wrote that function as a single application and despite that I am getting this error.

```
public class test {
public static void main(String a[])
{

    String keyword = "otterbox 3500 series { { waterproof case \\(clear\\) phones";

    if(keyword.contains("\\")){
        int l=0;
        int l2=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < keyword.length(); i++){         
            char c = keyword.charAt(i);
            if(c=='\\')l++;
            if (c == '!' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '&' ||
                    c == ':'  || c == '^' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c=='-'||
                    c == '{'  || c == '}' || c == '~'){
                keyword =keyword.replaceAll("\\\\"+c, ""+c); 
                l2++;               
            }
        }       

        if(l==1) keyword= keyword.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        if(l>1 && l2==1) keyword = keyword.replaceFirst("\\\\", "");
    }

    System.out.println("Final    "+keyword);


}}
```

It is throwing me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
 {

at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
at test.main(test.java:21)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
keyword = keyword.replaceAll("\\\\"+c, ""+c);
```

use this:

```
keyword = keyword.replaceAll("\\"+c, ""+c);
```

Reason is that `\\\\` means literal backspace character itself however you intend to escape those regex special characters using `\\` only.

Comment: thanks, but if i have a input like "otterbox 3500 series \{ \{ waterproof case \\\(clear\) phones" will this work?

Comment: Pls try and see if it works. If not then leave a comment and I will suggest something else.

Comment: [Please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068151/removing-escape-characters)

Comment: If i have to have / ( in my string , then it would be escaped as / / / ( , but while removing the escape it is like / / (, is it expected?

Comment: I am actually little confused between 2 very similar question of yours because in your other question I notice `keyword.replaceAll("\\\\\\"+c, ""+c);` which means a literal backspace char and then escaping the char denoted by c.

Answer (score 2):

The `{` and `}` characters are special characters in regex - they indicate repetition bounds (e.g. `ab{3,5}` which matches an `a` followed by three to five `b`s).

You need to escape this character accordingly in regexes, as `\{`.

---

In your particular case I think you're making things very hard for yourself (and inefficient) by consistently using regex replacements on parts of the sequence, *while iterating over it*.

If you're going to use regexes, just use a single regex replacement on the whole string which removes all of the characters you don't want.  E.g.

```
String keyword = "otterbox 3500 series { { waterproof case \\(clear\\) phones";
String result = keyword.replaceAll("[!()&:^\\[\\]\\-\\\\{}~]", "");
```

If you're going to iterate over the string and detect undesirable characters one at a time, then simply do this iteration and build up your output, skipping the characters you want to leave out.  E.g.:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < keyword.length(); i++){         
   char c = keyword.charAt(i);
   if (c == '!' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '&' || c == '\\'
                c == ':'  || c == '^' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c=='-'||
                c == '{'  || c == '}' || c == '~') {
      // skip it, don't add to result
   }
   else {
      result.add(c);
   }
}
```